# Flushing all resolved promises in Bluebird

Tags: unit-testing, promise, karma-jasmine, bluebird, flush

So I'm a new convert to Bluebird from angular and I'm trying to build unit tests for code that uses Bluebird promises. The code I want to test looks like this:

```
user {
    handleAuth(token) {
        console.log(token);
    },
    login(username, password, saveUsername) {
        return lib.login(username, password).then(this.handleAuth.bind(this));
    },
}
```

I've mocked out lib.login which returns a promise to instead return a resolved value like this

`lib.login.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));`

But the handler is not executed in the space of the unit test. In the Angular world, I would need to tell the $timeout service to flush and all the resolved promises would execute their chained methods. What's the equivalent in Bluebird?

Comment: There is no flushing. You just wait. Make the test asynchronous.

Comment: (If you really need this, you could use a custom scheduler, but I wouldn't recommend this)

Comment: Well that's a pain, it's really nice to be able to verify corner cases in asynch behaviors.

Comment: What do you mean by "corner cases"?

Comment: For instance, sometimes code assumes that a particular async call will still be pending when it runs, but if the server is fast enough, the call will have returned. To build a test that makes sure that this case is handled, I need to force the promise to resolve before I make the call to the code in question. Now I could wait on the call to finish myself, but then I have to change my code to return a promise that was otherwise only used internally. It's so much easier just to flush the promise and then make the call

Comment: Fundamentally, I've found flushing promises to be very usefull, and I'd like to be able to do so with Bluebird. If that's not possible, that's fine, but I already know other ways to do what I want to do, that isn't the point of the question.

Comment: Use setScheduler I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would `Promise.setScheduler` to control the scheduling:

```
const queue = new class CallbackQueue {
  constructor() { this._queue = []; }
  flush() { this._queue.forEach(fn => fn()); }
  push(fn) { this._queue.push(fn); }
}

Promise.setScheduler(fn => queue.push(fn);

// later
queue.flush(); // call every callback in a `then`.
```

Note that you might need to call `.flush` more than once as more promises are creates in the queue from further `then`s.

Note that this is **not** Promises/A+ compliant. I recommend just writing an async test.